# tcpdump for vpn tunnel

Tags: networking, vpn, packet-sniffers, tcpdump

I have two machines which are conected with vpn tunnel. I need to sniff the traffic (http requests) with tcpdump. I am using this command:

```
tcpdump -w log.pcap -s 64000 host
```

where host is my virtual ip, but I can only see the responses, not requests.
How can I see http requests?

Answer (score 1):

I have not understood your problem completely but as per my knowledge vpn works on IPSEC which    in turn work on two protocols either ah/esp

To capture `authentication header(AH)` traffic you can try this ..

`tcpdump -X -s0 protochain 51`

Similarly to capture `encapsulated security payload (ESP)` you can try this ...

`tcpdump -X -s0 protochain 50`

**Note:**
I have not understood your question exactly

Comment: Can you please take a look at question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13697806/android-vpn-client-how-to-save-incoming-and-outgoing-packetsof-type-bytebuffer

Answer (score 0):

Without more detail, I'm not sure what the issue is, but I think you're misunderstanding how tcpdump works.  Likely, you don't want to be specifying the IP, but, rather, the *interface*, using the "-i" parameter.  Likewise, if you *just* want to capture http requests, you probably want to specify that, too.  I think your command probably wants to look an awful lot more like this:

```
tcpdump -i <interface> -w log.pcap -s 64000 "port 80"
```